# Delegate set after View Controller is initialized creating issues with the Parse method QueryForTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I am using PFQueryTableViewController that requires a certain PFUser to be passed to it before the QueryForTableView is called. To solve this, I created a protocol in the PFQueryTableViewController that has a required method called userForProfileTableView.

```
@protocol profileTableViewDataSource <NSObject>

@required

-(PFUser *)userForProfileTableView;

@end
```

The previous view controller uses this method to set the PFUser. However, the previous view controller only sets itself as the dataSource in prepareForSegue:sender:completion. When this method is called, the queryForTableView and initWithCoder methods have already been called meaning there is no PFObject for the PFQueryTableViewClass to work with.

How can I get a reference to the PFQueryTableViewController directly after it is initialized or is there another way I can pass the PFUser before queryForTableView is called? Any help/ideas would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

code:

Both are subclasses of PFQueryTableViewController

First view controller which is the Data Source:

.h (not important)

.m

```
#import "FeedQueryTableViewController.h"
#import "FeedTableViewCell.h"

@interface FeedQueryTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation FeedQueryTableViewController{
    PFUser * userToPass;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Question";
    }
    return self;
}

-(PFQuery *)queryForTable{
    //First query for followed users
    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    [query whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"follow"];
    [query includeKey:@"toUser"];
    [query includeKey:@"fromUser"];

    //Second query for questions
    PFQuery * questionQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Question"];
    [questionQuery whereKey:@"User" matchesKey:@"toUser" inQuery:query];
    [questionQuery includeKey:@"User"];

    return questionQuery;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{

    FeedTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FeedTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    //Set values of cell

    [cell.usernameButton setTitle:[[object objectForKey:@"User"]username] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.usernameButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.usernameButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.questionTextView.text = [object objectForKey:@"Question"];

    return cell;
}

-(PFUser *)userForProfileTableView{

    //This happens before the other class

    if (userToPass != nil){
        NSLog(@"%@", userToPass.username);
        return userToPass;}
    else{
        return userToPass;
}
}

-(void)userButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    //Type checking is sketchy here and could lead to potential crashes
    PFObject * object = [[[self queryForTable]findObjects] objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    userToPass = [object objectForKey:@"User"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userProfile" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    ProfileTableViewController * ptvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    ptvc.dataSource = self;
}

@end
```

View Controller which contains the protocol and is retrieving the PFUser to base Tableview data on

.h

```
//
//  ProfileTableViewController.h
//  qSocialNetwork
//
//  Created by Sam Kirkiles on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Sam Kirkiles. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@protocol profileTableViewDataSource <NSObject>

@required

-(PFUser *)userForProfileTableView;

@end

@interface ProfileTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PFUser * userToDisplay;

@property (weak) id <profileTableViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  ProfileTableViewController.m
//  qSocialNetwork
//
//  Created by Sam Kirkiles on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Sam Kirkiles. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ProfileTableViewController.h"

@interface ProfileTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProfileTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.dataSource userForProfileTableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Activity";
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)objectsWillLoad{
    [super objectsWillLoad];
    self.userToDisplay = [self.dataSource userForProfileTableView];
    if (self.userToDisplay != nil) {
        NSLog(@"sdfsfd");
        [self queryForTable];
        //A user has been passed to this view controller
    }else{
        //User the current user as a backup
        //This feature will be added later

    }

}

-(PFQuery *)queryForTable{
    if (self.userToDisplay != nil){
    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Question"];
    [query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:self.userToDisplay];
        return query;
    }
    PFQuery *noUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Question"];
    return noUserQuery;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Question"];

    return cell;
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. For some reason, I had to hit Project then Clean. This for some reason made the program work. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when attempting to set an object for queryForTable method on the previous view controller. The solution I came up with was to create a custom initializer that sets the object and then calls the super initializer. 
e.g.

```
- (id)initWithParent:(PFObject *)parent
{
    self.parent = parent;
    self = [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
       ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

I know it's a less than elegant solution, but it was the only way I could get the queryForTable methd to use my  object to query without having to rerun the query in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that would fix the problem but I am using storyboards and it initializes the view controllers in the background. It seems like this Parse class was built with xib in mind. How can I call the initializer myself instead of the compiler writing it for me?